# SharePoint 2013 Datasheet view is read only

Tags: document-library, datasheet

I have created a DropOffLibrary, added a few documents. Then created a DataSheet View to allow quick edit of library properties. However, the view shows as read-only and does not allow inline editing. I have set versioning settings not require check-in. Also tried to include all columns without success. However, if I go to menu and run **Quick Edit** it works fine.

Anyone, has more suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that it was "Edit" column included in DataSheet view that was causing the grid to be read only. In addition to Versioning setting.